# Mysql - Should I use ID columns?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a doubt about best practices and how the database engine works.

Suppose I create a table called Employee, with the following columns:

- SS ID (Primary Key)
- Name
- Sex
- Age

The thing is.. I see a lot of databases that all its tables has and aditional column called ID, wich is a sequencial number. Should I put and ID field in my table here? I mean, it already has a Primary Key to be indexed. Will the database works faster with a sequencial ID field? I dont see how it helps if I wont use it to link or research any table.

Does it helps? If so, why, what happens in the database?

thanks!

EDIT -----
This is just a silly example. Forget about the SS_ID, I know there are better ways for choosing a primary key. The main topi is because some people I know just ask me to add the collumn named ID, even if I know we wont use it for any SQL query. They just think it helps the database's performance in some way, specially because some database tools like Microsoft Access always asks us if we want it to add this new column.

This is wrong, right?

Comment: "it already has a Primary Key to be indexed"   which one?. Are you sure that you can make one of the others unique and not null'd?.  Then you don't need an int primary key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual performance gain in having a sequential `id` is going to depend a lot on how you use the table.

- If you're using some ORM framework, these generally work better having a sequential ID of an integral type [1], which is typically achieved with an sequential id column.
- If you don't use an ORM framework, having an `id`key that you never use and a surrogate `ss_id` key which is effectively what you always use makes little sense.
- If you're referencing `employees` from other database table (foreign-key), then it'll probably be more efficient to have an `id` column, as storing that integer is going to consume less space in the child tables than storing the `ss_id` (which I assume is a `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`) everywhere.

On the `ss_id`, assuming it's a social security number (looks like it would be), there might be legal & privacy concerns attached to it that you should care about - my answer assumes you do have valid reasons to have social security numbers in your database, and that you would be legally allowed to use & store them.

[1] This is usually explained by the fact the ORM frameworks rely on having highly specialized cache mechanisms, that are tailored for typical ORM use - which usually implies having a sequential `id` primary key, and letting application deal with actual business identity. This is in fact related to consideration very similar to these of the "foreign key" considerations.

Comment: The SS_ID is just an example (a bad one, sorry). I'm asking this because some people I know just ask me to add the collumn named ID, iven if I know we wont use it for any SQL query. They just think it helps the database's performance in some way. This is wrong, right?

Comment: Well, as I state in my answer, it helps DB performance *if* it is used as part of cross-table relationships (foreign keys), or *if* most SQL against the table filter on the `id` column.

Comment: @Romain: Can you justify the comment "these generally work better having a sequential ID of an integral type"?

Answer (score 6):

If SS means "Social Security", I'd strongly advise against using that as a PK.  An auto-incremented identity is the way to go.

Using keys with business logic built in is a bad idea.  Lots of people are sensitive about giving SS information.  Your app could be eliminating part of their audience if they use SS as primary key.  Laws like HIPPA can make it impossible for you to use.

Comment: +1 on advising against storing the social security number altogether.

Comment: You are supposed to hash or obfuscate the SS id  before storing it. And SO you can't use it as primary key. it will be inefficient and insecure.

Comment: @ngen It can be encrypted in such ways that it's still useable as a primary key. Performance hit of doing so isn't that big since these IDs are usually quite short.

Comment: The SS_ID is just an example (a bad one, sorry). I'm asking this because some people I know just ask me to add the collumn named ID, iven if I know we wont use it for any SQL query. They just think it helps the database's performance in some way. This is wrong, right?

Comment: I think you should research more before deciding that it's wrong.

Comment: @Romain That will be inefficient(considerably on large amount of data) . plus more difficult in making other queries .

Comment: @JoãoGuilherme You should never use the SSN for legal reasons. Technically it is no problem--after all, it *is* the PK in some government databases.

Answer (score 4):

US Social Security numbers are *not* sufficiently identifying. And banks certainly *do not* use them in that way. Not everybody has one. Errors result in duplicates. Foreigners don't have them. They are far too fragile to use as a database PK.

Most importantly: **the are resused after death**

Do some research: [SSN as Primary Key](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ssn%20as%20primary%20key)

Comment: Depends on the use case. Also, one cannot just "assume" they're referring to US numbers. Hence this answer is, IMO, extremely incomplete.

Comment: Perhaps incomplete, but even what's there seems definitive enough for me.  Other countries would have to face the same issues.

Comment: The OP mentionned `ss_id` merely as a (badly chosen) example. Core question was about best practice of including a sequential `id` column.

Comment: Doesn't matter now, but that didn't come out until later.

Comment: That's where more study, not SO questions, is needed.  I don't think it's a one-size fits all answer.  SS might be badly chosen, but it's representative of why you don't want biz logic in keys.  I feel like the OP is looking for an "answer" without understanding all the trade-offs.

Comment: The question was never about the SS_ID, or how can I choose keys. Sorry if you didnt understand my question. I was just wondering if adding a new sequencial ID column in all tables would help the database in some way I dont know, even if i'm sure they wont be forign keys or used in any sql query. I know some databases that are made this way and people who insists that we need to add this magic field, even if they dont know why or when it will be used.

Answer (score 3):

What's more important (obviously) is that you have a primary key, as long as the data you put use for that primary key will be uniquely identifiable.  In your example, SSN's are uniquely identifiable which is why banks use them and will work. The problem with this example is that your Employee ID is likely to be used as a Foreign Key in other tables, which means you're taking personal information (that is legally protected) and spraying it across your data model.  You might do better using an Auto Incremented field in this case.